# How much time does it take in Earth to generate the energy supply that the sun produces in one second?

Tags: energy, earth, sun

According to this article which I ignore if it's correct [The amount of energy the sun emits every second is](https://plus.google.com/+PhilipPlait/posts/XVPiicbp1vH) , the amount of energy the sun emits by second is $4\times10^{33}$ ergs . And according to this other article [World energy consumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_energy_consumption) the total energy supply per year in Earth is $5.67\times10^{20}$ joules. If I'm not wrong that would make it needed hundred of thousands of years necessary for the Earth to generate the energy supply that's produced in one second in the sun. Is the answer in this order of magnitude or the data provided by the article and/or calculations are wrong and the time is much higher or lower?